# Average the value based on count of a column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with wrong views, I am expecting my new tables with values below by manipulating the existing table. 
Basically, My query should be if more than 1 V1 is present then its value should be averaged among A1.

This is what I tried so far,

```
select VID,AID,Avg(Views)
from T1
having count(V1) > 1
```

But this is giving me wrong results, I think this should be a subquery, any help on correcting my query.

Available: Table with wrong views

```
+-----+-----+-------+
| AID | VID | Views |
+-----+-----+-------+
| A1  | V1  |   600 |
| A2  | V1  |   600 |
| A3  | V1  |   600 |
| A4  | V2  |   200 |
| A5  | V2  |   200 |
| A6  | V3  |   50  |
+-----+-----+-------+
```

Expected output:

```
+-----+-----+-------+
| AID | VID | Views |
+-----+-----+-------+
| A1  | V1  |   200 |
| A2  | V1  |   200 |
| A3  | V1  |   200 |
| A4  | V2  |   100 |
| A5  | V2  |   100 |
| A6  | V3  |   50  |
+-----+-----+-------+
```

Comment: `WHERE VID = 'V1' AND AID = 'A1'` will surely do the trick? What does the table itself look like?

Comment: How can I get it for all rows

Comment: Get what, the average? Try `GROUP BY`. As I've said, please show your raw schema.

Comment: There's no column `V1` but value `'V1'` within the table.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a denominator for `count` that would come from an aggregated subquery :

```
SELECT T1.AID, T1.VID, T1.Views / cnt AS Views 
  FROM T1
  JOIN ( SELECT VID, count(VID) AS cnt FROM T1 GROUP BY VID ) T2
    ON T2.VID = T1.VID
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0f0d41afcbdc8a1b600c436d9af99558)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want simple division and a window function:

```
select aid, VID, Views / count(*) over (partition by vid)
from T1;
```

Comment: provided the DB version is 8.0+

Answer (score 0):

an aggregation function with  columns without aggregation functions need  a group by

```
select VID,AID,Avg(Views)
from T1
group by VID, AID
having count(V1) > 1
```